# What is the difference between == and === in Dart?

Tags: dart

Does Dart support == and === ? What is the difference between equality and identity?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Dart supports `==` for equality and `identical(a, b)` for identity. Dart no longer supports the `===` syntax.

Use `==` for equality when you want to check if two objects are "equal". You can implement the `==` method in your class to define what equality means. For example:

```dart
class Person {
  String ssn;
  String name;

  Person(this.ssn, this.name);

  // Define that two persons are equal if their SSNs are equal
  bool operator ==(other) {
    return (other is Person && other.ssn == ssn);
  }
}

main() {
  var bob =  Person('111', 'Bob');
  var robert =  Person('111', 'Robert');

  print(bob == robert); // true

  print(identical(bob, robert)); // false, because these are two different instances
}
```

Note that the semantics of `a == b` are:

- If either `a` or `b` are `null`, return `identical(a, b)`
- Otherwise, return `a.==(b)`

Use `identical(a, b)` to check if two variables reference the same instance. The [identical](https://api.dart.dev/be/175003/dart-core/identical.html) function is a top-level function found in `dart:core`.

Comment: Additional thoughts on equality and what to watch out for by Kevin Moore:
http://work.j832.com/2014/05/equality-and-dart.html

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that the use of the `identical` function in dart has some caveats as mentioned by this github issue [comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/563#issuecomment-108304500):

> The specification has been updated to treat identical between doubles
> like this:
>
> The identical() function is the predefined dart function that returns
> true iff its two arguments are either:
>
> - The same object.
> - Of type int and have the same numeric value.
> - Of type double, are not NaNs, and have the same numeric value.

What this entails is that even though [everything](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts) in dart is an object, and `f` and `g` are different objects, the following prints `true`.

```
int f = 99;
int g = 99;
print(identical(f, g));
```

because ints are identical by their value, not reference.

---

So to answer your question, `==` is used to identify if two objects have the same value, but the `identical` is used to test for referential equality except in the case of `double` and `int` as identified by the excerpt above.

See: [equality-and-relational-operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#equality-and-relational-operators)

Answer (score 4):

As DART is said to be related to javascript, where the === exists, I wish not be downvoted very quickly.

Identity as a concept means that 1 equals 1, but 1.0 doesn't equal 1, nor does false equal 0, nor does "2" equal 2, even though each one *evaluates* to each other and 1==1.0 returns true.

Comment: 1.0 == 1 because JavaScript only has one type of number. false != 0. "2" != 2.

Comment: Dart's only relation to JavaScript in this is that Dart fixes the broken stuff by never (OK, almost never) automatically coercing values. And identity as a concept only means that you can tell if some references in the system point to the same object, it has nothing to do with values and their equality.

Comment: Identity as concept in javascript has all to do with values. a=7.5/2;b=1.25*3; a===b, because they are the same type and evaluate to same value -- not because they internally reference after some calculations to a literal "3.5", which never existed.

Comment: Not really. The === operator in JavaScript doesn't test for identity but for equality without coercion. That's probably the reason why it was changed in Dart -- JavaScript people could think that it relates to equality.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that in Dart, `identical` works similarly to Javascript, where `(5.0 == 5)` is `true`, but `identical(5.0, 5)` is `false`.

Comment: Dart doesn't actually coerce things like == does in JavaScript. It's just that JavaScript only has one number type. Hence, "5" == 5.0 is true in JavaScript, but false in Dart.

Comment: `identical(5.0, 5)` is `true` in Dart.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad `identical(5.0, 5)` is `true` when Dart is transpiled to JavaScript (since the underlying JavaScript objects are the same). `identical(5.0, 5)` is `false` in the Dart VM.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, didn't know that, but what Dart is transpiled to on DartPad and Mobile device?

Comment: Dart in a browser (including DartPad) uses JavaScript.  Dart everywhere else uses the Dart VM.