# Is it possible to use .equals() method like Java in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, equals

I'm a Java developer and the newbie in Dart.

When I compare two objects in Dart, it only has `==` operator which helps me compare two logical memory addresses of two objects in Dart. How can I compare two objects to be the same like Java without be preparing this code below? It makes me tired to prepare entity's class so I wonder that have any Dart's ways for that?

```
class MyClass {
    final MySubClass mySubClass;

    MyClass({this.mySubClass});

    bool equals(Object other) => identical(this, other) || other is MyClass && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && something.equals(other.mySubClass);
}

class MySubClass {
    final String something;

    MySubClass({this.something});

    bool equals(Object other) => identical(this, other) || other is MySubClass && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && something == other.something;
}
```

Comment: You will found answer here : http://pchalin.blogspot.com/2014/04/defining-equality-and-hashcode-for-dart.html

Comment: Thank U alot. Let me check this blog.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275506/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-dart for a good explanation of the `identical` function (equivalent to Java `==`) and Dart's `operator==` (equivalent to Java `equals`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart language don't have equals method. According [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-equatable-package-simplify-equality-comparisons-1a96a3fc4864), I have to use `Equatable Package`.

Comment: equatable uses same == operator

Comment: article quote `Equatable overrides == and hashCode for you so you don’t have to waste your time writing lots of boilerplate code.` so you said `I have to use Equatable Package ` not true, you could use it but you don't have to used it

Comment: Some one did edited my question. I want an equal method which compare the value but not memory location. :/

Answer (score 4):

```
@override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is Class &&
              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
              id == other.property;

@override
int get hashCode => property.hashCode;
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

## Equal method same as JAVA

I build it as an extension because I am not really a fan of using it at function
and if you pass it as function it will make any sense of look any similiar to the JAVA functionality

```dart
extension Equals on String {
  bool equals(Object anObject) {
    if (identical(this, anObject)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (anObject is String) {
      String anotherString = anObject;
      int n = codeUnits.length;
      if (n == anotherString.codeUnits.length) {
        List<int> v1 = codeUnits;
        List<int> v2 = anotherString.codeUnits;
        int i = 0;
        while (n-- != 0) {
          if (v1[i] != v2[i]) {
            return false;
          }
          i++;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

### Example

```dart
bool isEqual(String str) {
  String object = 'Your String';
  return str.equals(object);
}
```

It will check the equality between two objects OR in our case between TWO Strings