# How to create two same instance widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

everybody, I just test the "const" and "new" keyword in Dart, and I found that:
If I want to create the exactly same instance, I must:

1. add the "const" keyword before the constructor declaration.
2. add the "const" keyword before any place I want to use the object.

like this:

```
class A {
  final int x;
  const A(this.x);
}

// when use
var a = const A(0);
var b = const A(0);
identical(a,b); // this is true, they are same instance
```

---------------------------  OK, so far, this is ok, but !!!! ----------------------------
When I also want to create two same "widgets", I failed!!

like this:

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  final int x;

  const A(this.x,{Key? key })
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

// when use
var a = const A(0);
var b = const A(0);
identical(a,b); // this is false!!!!!!  why?????????
```

So....  Someone can tell me how to create two same instance widgets??  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SOF.

It's because Dart first instantiates an A then makes it constant, please don't confuse constant with `static`.

**The reason the first sample gives identical=true is because both objects have similar `hashCode`.**
(https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html)

hashCode is used for object comparison operations like ==

You should write this way, which is actually useless!:

```
var z = const A(0);
var a = z;
var b = z
identical(a,b);
```

Or you should override == and hashCode

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think  'identical() is not equivalent to 'equal' which is the concept you just said, related info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275506/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-dart

Comment: 'identical' seems to be used for checking whether two object is same instance.